# Android lint SharedPreferences.Editor.apply() warning

Tags: android, gradle, lint

I have updated to the latest Android SDK Tools (23.0.0), Platform-tools (20.0.0), Android Studio Gradle plugin (0.12.+) and suddenly I am receiving a weird Lint issue report saying that I should use apply() instead of commit() as apply() is asynchronous and will allow UI Thread to proceed as commit() will be blocking it for writing. Cool. But still I am getting this:

[image]

Is it an Lint bug, or am I missing something here?

Obviously I could suppress this warning, but I find it pointless and ignorant of the root cause.

EDIT: This will also be raised when building app from command line.

Comment: I think it is bug. Try to split your long "dot" expression in several lines - local variable assigning, put one string, put second string and apply

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. Still, if it would work then it would be a workaround to satisfy Lint warning without any actual benefit for code readability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a Lint bug, indeed. More specifically, [this one](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72828).

The error seems to be in the `CommitFinder` inner class of [`SharedPrefsDetector`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/lint/libs/lint-checks/src/main/java/com/android/tools/lint/checks/SharedPrefsDetector.java):

```
@Override
public boolean visitMethodInvocation(MethodInvocation node) {
    ...
    String name = node.astName().astValue();
    boolean isCommit = "commit".equals(name);
    if (isCommit || "apply".equals(name)) {
        ...

        if (returnValueIgnored) {
            String message = "Consider using apply() instead; commit writes "
                    + "its data to persistent storage immediately, whereas "
                    + "apply will handle it in the background";
            mContext.report(ISSUE, node, mContext.getLocation(node), message,
                                null);
        }
```

I guess the idea was to give this warning *only if you didn't assign the return value of `commit()` to anything* (this part works), but they forgot to check the `isCommit` flag. :)

Comment: The say here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36998746 that they fixed it and released it. What do I need to update to get the fix?